# Absolute path in Vue.js

Tags: symfony, vue.js

I'm working in a vue file inside of a Symfony project and I want to find the absolute path from a route. Usually I do something like this:

```
this.$http({
     url: 'products/edit/'+product.id,
     method: 'PUT',
     params : params
[...]
```

and it works great. But now I don't need to use `this.$http` because I'm trying to do this:

```
 <div>
    {{ getUrl(product) }}
</div>
```

and I have my function:

```
getUrl(product) : {
     let url = '/products/edit'+product.id
     return url
}
```

but obviously it only displays `/products/edit/xxx`
instead of `mysite.com/products/edit/xxx` in production or `localhost/products/edit/xxx` in local.

In my routing file I have:

```
update_product:
path:   /products/edit/{product}
defaults: { _controller: RBProductsBundle:Product:edit }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
methods: 
  getFullUrl (product) {
    return location.origin + this.getUrl(product)
  }
}

...
{{ getFullUrl(product) }}
...
```

`Location` object has info about the origin & path to the currently opened page.

[Read more about "location" here](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/obj_location.asp)